# How to change the default arguments of a function within a function in R

Tags: r, list, function, arguments, resampling

I have a list from which I want to randomly sample with replacements using the Map function. The problem is the "sample" function default argument for replacement is "replace = FALSE" and I do not know how to change the argument to "replace = TRUE" within the Map function.

I'm guessing you would have to write a custom function but I feel like there is a easier way to do it.

What normally works if I want to randomly sample 100 elements from each list

```
 Map(sample, list, 100)
```

But I want to sample with replacement to something like this but it gives the following error which makes sense but I do not how to work around this.

```
 Map(sample(replace = TRUE), list, 200)
```

> Error in sample(, replace = TRUE) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: Like this perhaps? `Map(sample, list(1:10000,1:20000), 100, replace=TRUE)`

Comment: What's wrong with specifying the data set within the sample call? like this:`Map(sample(x=list, replace=T), list, 200)`